# "Could not open the requested SVN filesystem" after copying the repo-files to an other server

Tags: linux, svn

My old subversion server (Fedora 10, Apache with mod_dav_svn) crashed and the only thing I have is a backup of the filesystem.

I've configured the new server (now CentOS 5) exactly the same way and copied the files from the backup, but I get this error: "Could not open the requested SVN filesystem"
(New repositories are working...)

What could I try to get the repositories working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately CentOS 5's subversion is quite old, 1.4.2, whereas Fedora 10's is newer, 1.5.4. The fsfs format must have changed between the two (look for a version file in the repository directory) and your older subversion on CentOS can't read the newer version generated on 1.5.4.

You have two options:

1. Install a temporary copy of 1.5.4 or later (or e.g. set up a Fedora 10 VM to use the copy there), use `svnadmin dump` from 1.5.4 to back up the repository then load this into a new repository using `svnadmin load` with the 1.4.2 tools. This may be slow, and you'll also have to copy over any hooks etc. You'll also lose the server-side support for svn:mergeinfo attributes.
2. Install a newer version of subversion on your machine. You can either build this yourself - getting a Fedora SRPM is a good start, although it will usually need a few fix-ups - or you can set up your system to update from [RPMForge](http://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge/Using), either in its entirety or just for subversion and its dependencies - and install their up-to-date builds of 1.6.x. You'll get all the improvements of 1.6 and keep the svn:mergeinfo attribute support, but you'll no longer have a strictly-RHEL-5-compatible system (if you're bothered about that). For future note: as in the discussion below you must restart apache, e.g. `/sbin/service httpd restart`, after updating the installed subversion.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answer!

I've updated subversion using RPMForge to version 1.6.12, but the error is still there.

Comment: Oh :-/ Sorry for encouraging you to upgrade then when that wasn't the answer. Could it be a server permissions problem somehow - are you seeing the error in apache-hosted SVN or with command-line `svn ls file://etc` or both? I often get bitten by SELinux permissions so if it's broken through apache only then I'd try turning SELinux off. Or it may be necessary to `svnadmin upgrade` the repository before it'll work with 1.6, but I've encouraged you do to enough drastic things already I'm not really sure about suggesting that

Comment: Oh, you're using a BDB repository not FSFS? In which case I might have given you bad advice: you might need to be using the exact version of Berkley DB to read it - I don't know the compatibility between BDB versions. Or maybe you can do some sort of BDB upgrade? I don't know. The 'Expected FS format' is 2 for 1.4.x, 3 for 1.5.x and 4 for 1.6.x so it looks to me that at least your apache is still running the 1.4.2 mod_dav_svn and libraries - did you restart it with `/sbin/service httpd restart` or similar? The simplest option now might be to set up a Fedora 10 VM and check that still reads it.

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't restarted the Apache... :/ Now it works fine! Thank you very much for your good help!